# How to create an array of words to ignore when plurals ('s') are omitted from search terms Wordpress search

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a novice with code and currently trying to learn everything I can. I've put together some script to omit the 's' from search queries in wordpress. However, I'm looking to omit this function on certain words. How would I create the array to do this? Thanks

```
function mySearchFilterFunction($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search) {
        $search_term = $query->get('s');
        if (substr($search_term, -1) == 's'){
            $search_term = substr($search_term, 0, -1);
        }
        $query->set('s', $search_term);
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mySearchFilterFunction');
```

Comment: What do you mean by _“to omit the 's' from search queries in wordpress”_?

Comment: The 's' is removed from the end of search terms with 's' on the end, to improve the quality of the results shown

Comment: Well you would need to split the entered search term into individual “words” first - for starters, a simple explode at any space characters might do (that would not catch cases where the user entered a search term with different white space characters, but you can extend that part of the functionality later.) Then you can loop over those words, and for example check if they are contained in an array of given words using `in_array`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I'm not 100% what you mean:

My two ideas were to either :


1. Create an array of words to ignore. So if the word appears and we we look to remove the S, if the word is in the list, we don't remove the S.


2. Have a new table in the database and have a way for admins to add words there, then we can check the word in the DB and see if it exists, if it does, allow it to search that work, if not, then we remove the "s" and search with the new word.

Comment: My attempt above doesn't allow for the omission on specific words from the functionality, so I'd just appreciate a guide on what would be best to add from a code perspective to the code created.

Comment: Start with a hard-coded array inside the function - you can worry about how to make this maintainable by the admin later. Then, as I said, loop over the words you got from the search term, and check if it is contained in your array of “forbidden” words. Perhaps best to add all search words to a new array inside the loop, either the original or the modified version. Then at the end, you implode this array again with a space as the divider.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do this in the future. I worked it out - I hope this helps! :)

```
function mySearchFilterFunction($query) {
  if(!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search) {
     //### Words to skip
  $skip_words = array('diaries', 'stylus');

      //### Get the search term
  $search_term = trim(strtolower($query->get('s')));

    //### Check if the last letter of the search term is an S
    //### Also check to see if the word is in the skip word array
  if(substr($search_term, -1) == 's' && !in_array($search_term, $skip_words)){
      $search_term = substr($search_term, 0, -1);
  }

  //### Set the search term
  $query->set('s', $search_term);
  }
}
```